# What does the underscore mean in $this->_objectProperty?

Tags: php, oop, object

I have encountered an instance where object properties look like this:

```
$this->property
```

and this:

```
$this->_property
```

What does the `_` mean before `->`? What difference does it make in terms of coding?

Answer (score -1):

Usually it is used for reminding the variable/function is private.